# Mapping a single controller to several beans in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I need to create several beans for my static pages with different IDs using a single controller class which has an attribute to define a jsp name to be displayed.

I used to do this with an older version using FormControllers but I cannot in version 3.2.4
I checked several topics and understand that spring beans are singletons but
I want to know if this is possible or if there is a work-around without creating empty controller classes for each page.

Here is the BaseController class:

```
    public class BaseController extends AbstractController {

    public String contentPage;

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("common/mainlayout");

        if(contentPage != null && !contentPage.equals("")){
            mv.addObject("mainContent", "maincontent/" + contentPage);
            mv.addObject("mainMenuSelect", contentPage);
        }

        return mv;
    }

    public String getContentPage() {
        return contentPage;
    }
    public void setContentPage(String contentPage) {
        this.contentPage = contentPage;
    }
}
```

Here is my mapping in spring-servlet.xml Note that I also tried defining class of each bean using my BaseController

```
<bean id="urlMapping"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>

            <!-- STATIC PAGES -->
            <prop key="/index.dlg">indexPageController</prop>
            <prop key="/faq.dlg">faqController</prop>
            <prop key="/howto.dlg">howtoController</prop>
            <prop key="/contactUs.dlg">contactUsController</prop>
            <prop key="/aboutUs.dlg">aboutUsController</prop>

            <!-- DYNAMIC PAGES -->
            <prop key="/postBox.dlg">postBoxController</prop>
            <prop key="/invoiceBox.dlg">invoiceController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="siteInterceptor" />
        </list>
    </property>

</bean>

<bean id="siteInterceptor" class="com.entegrator.spring.interceptor.SiteInterceptor"></bean>

<!-- STATIC PAGE CONTROLLERS -->
<bean id="baseController" abstract="true" class="com.entegrator.spring.controller.BaseController" />

<bean id="indexPageController" parent="baseController" >
    <property name="contentPage" value="index" />
</bean>

<bean id="faqController" parent="baseController" >
    <property name="contentPage" value="faq" />
</bean>

<bean id="howtoController" parent="baseController" >
    <property name="contentPage" value="howto" />
</bean>

<bean id="contactUsController" parent="baseController" >
    <property name="contentPage" value="contactUs" />
</bean>

<bean id="aboutUsController" parent="baseController" >
    <property name="contentPage" value="aboutUs" />
</bean>
<!-- STATIC PAGE CONTROLLERS END -->


<!-- DYNAMIC PAGE CONTROLLERS -->
<bean id="postBoxController" class="com.entegrator.spring.controller.PostBoxController">
    <property name="postBoxManager" ref="postBoxManager" />
</bean>
<bean id="invoiceController" class="com.entegrator.spring.controller.InvoiceController">
    <property name="postBoxManager" ref="postBoxManager" />
</bean>
<!-- DYNAMIC PAGE CONTROLLERS END -->
```

my web.xml is:

```
<display-name>EntegratorPortal</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>


    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.dlg</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Here is my error log:

```
 SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot map handler 'faqController' to URL path [/base*]: There is already handler 'indexPageController' mapped.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:865)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot map handler 'faqController' to URL path [/base*]: There is already handler 'indexPageController' mapped.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.registerHandler(AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.registerHandler(AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:266)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.detectHandlers(AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.java:82)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.initApplicationContext(AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.java:58)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:119)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(WebApplicationObjectSupport.java:72)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:73)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:117)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    ... 32 more
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why do they need to be request scoped?! There is nothing in there that needs a request scope, so why this added complexity. There is nothing preventing you from doing what you want, but you also have a `ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping` somewhere which is also detecting the controllers (again?). At least something is resulting in duplicate mappings.

Comment: I removed the scope parameter, was just testing it anyway. I guess your suggestion about an extra handler is due to the url warning (URL path [/base*]) and you are probably right. Yet I did not add any extra handler. I just added all spring jars to make sure I created the project fast as possible. Is there a way to check if I have an extra handler for controllers and remove it?

Comment: There is a `ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping` configured somewhere, however you can only map a single controller to an URL.

Comment: Ok I found it, there was a definition for ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping somewhere in the spring-servlet.xml from the old code that I forgot to delete. Totally my fault :( Couldn't have notice it without you though .. Thanks

Comment: Well the stacktrace clearly states that the `ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping` failed to start correctly so it must be coming from somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not simply have methods annotated with @RequestMapping(value="/foo" method="RequestMethod.GET") within your one controller for each of your pages?

That seems to be the simplest solution.

Your controller would look something like this:

```
@Controller
public class BaseController
{

    @RequestMapping(value="/index", method="RequestMethod.GET")
    public String returnIndexPage()
    {
        return "Your Index JSP Page Location Here";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/faq", method="RequestMethod.GET")
    public String returnFAQPage()
    {
         return("Your FAQ JSP Page Location Here";
    }
```

etc...

You could modify it to only return your content page variable if you like.

That would certainly work too.

Let me know how you get on.

Comment: The way I created this project is standard for all of our projects so I dont have much option to use this solution unless I really have to but I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Why not leverage the new spring `@Controller` and `@RequestMapping` annotations? That way you only need a single controller.

```
@Controller
public class StaticController {


    @RequestMapping({"/index.dlg", "/howto", // The rest of your mappings}
    public String handleStatic(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
        String contentPage = //Extract page-name from request 
        model.addObject("mainContent", "maincontent/" + contentPage);
        model.addObject("mainMenuSelect", contentPage);  
        return "common/mainlayout";      
    }
}
```

This controller can then be detected and setup by using the `RequestMappingHandlermapping` and executed by the `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` (those are registered by using `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in your xml configuration).

Or utilize springs view-controller (`<mvc:view-controller .. />`) and add an interceptor to add the needed attributes to the model

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/index.dlg" view-name="common/mainlayout" />
<mvc:view-controller path="/faq.dlg" view-name="common/mainlayout" />

<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mapping path="/index.dlg" />
        <mapping path="/faq/dlg" />
        <bean class="YourInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Drawback of this approach is that you are basically duplicating your mappings (once for the controller and once for the interceptor).

Links

1. Implementing Controllers [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-controller)
2. View Controllers [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-view-controller)
3. Configuring Interceptors [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-interceptors)